# What is an "automation-compatible language"?

Tags: com, programming-languages, automation

I have found many references to this term on the web, especially on Microsoft's MSDN website, and even lists of such languages. However, I can't find a definition of this term. (Is it something as simple as a language for which a COM interface has been implemented?)

Please let me know if you know of a link to a definition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Microsoft Windows applications
>   programming, OLE Automation (later
>   renamed by Microsoft to just
>   Automation,[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_Automation)[2] although the old
>   term remained in widespread use), is
>   an inter-process communication
>   mechanism based on Component Object
>   Model (COM) that was intended for use
>   by scripting languages – originally
>   Visual Basic – but now are used by
>   languages run on Windows.[3] It
>   provides an infrastructure whereby
>   applications called automation
>   controllers can access and manipulate
>   (i.e. set properties of or call
>   methods on) shared automation objects
>   that are exported by other
>   applications.

[From Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_Automation)

Answer (score 5):

Stripped down to bare essentials, to understand COM you have to understand GUIDs and IUnknown.  The equivalent for Automation is ProgIDs and IDispatch.

A ProgID helps you create a COM coclass.  A typical ProgID is "Word.Automation", the progid for Microsoft Word.  You'll find them listed in the Registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.  A typical name for a helper function in your language is CreateObject().  You pass it the ProgID, optionally a machine name, and you get back an interface reference.  Which you can then use to make method calls and get/set properties.

The language runtime uses the IDispatch interface (retrieved with IUnknown::QueryInterface) to discover the names and parameters of the methods that are implemented by the COM server.  This is called late-binding, the way any scripting language uses Automation.  It has only 4 methods:

- IDispatch::GetTypeInfoCount(), returns 1 if the server can provide type info
- IDispatch::GetTypeInfo(), returns type information, helpful to make type-safe calls
- IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames(), maps an identifier name to a number
- IDispatch::Invoke(), calls a numbered method or property getter/setter.

That's all it takes.

Comment: here is someone who knows more than googling the entry, unlike me. I salute you sir